# Третья нормальная форма

Tags: sql, база-данных

В русскоязычной и англоязычной статьях про третью нормальную форму отношения весьма странные формулировки транзитивной функциональной зависимости.

(Отношение находится в третьей нормальной форме, если находится во второй, и не существует транзитивной функциональной зависимости между потенциальным ключом и неключевым атрибутом)

Русскоязычная википедия: функциональная зависимость X → Z является транзитивной, если существует такое Y, что X → Y → Z, и ни одна из функциональных зависимостей
X → Y, Y → Z, X →  Z не является тривиальной.
Можно выбрать в качестве X один потенциальный ключ, в качестве Y другой потенциальный ключ, который не содержится в X, а в качестве Z любой неключевой атрибут. Однако простейшие случаи таких отношений должны быть в 3НФ согласно альтернативному определению Карло Заниоло.

(Альтернативное определение Карло Заниоло заключается в том, что для любой функциональной зависимости вида X → {A} верно хотя бы одно из трех условий: X - суперключ, A лежит в X, A - ключевой атрибут.)

Англоязычная википедия: функциональная зависимость X → Z является транзитивной, если существует такое Y, что X → Y → Z, все X, Y, Z различны, и не выполняется Y → X. Ближе к правде, но все еще можно взять в качестве X потенциальный ключ, в качестве Y множество из двух неключевых атрибутов, а в качестве Z одноэлементное подмножество Y.

Не было бы разумным заменить условие неравенства X, Y, Z условием нетривиальности функциональной зависимости Y → Z? Тогда все будет в согласии с Карло Заниоло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не было бы разумным заменить условие неравенства X, Y, Z условием
>   нетривиальности функциональной зависимости Y → Z? Тогда все будет в
>   согласии с Карло Заниоло.

Нет, так как в таком случае остаётся возможность существования тривиальной функциональной зависимости X → Y, а условие из англоязычной статьи "все X, Y, Z различны" и из русскоязычной статьи "...и ни одна из функциональных зависимостей X → Y, Y → Z, X → Z не является тривиальной" это запрещают.

Comment: Почему попарное неравенство X, Y, Z запрещает тривиальность X → Y?

Однако и текущие формулировки приводят к казусам и несовместимости с альтернативным определением. Есть какой-то более надежный источник?

Казалось бы в тривиальности X → Y нет ничего плохого, это тем не менее некоторое упрощение функциональной зависимости с потенциального ключа на некоторое меньшее подмножество его атрибутов, то есть нам должно хотеться нормализовать его.

Comment: Ну и при доказательстве эквивалентности видно, что ровно эти два свойства требуются (отсутствие Y → X и нетривиальность Y → Z). Может быть тогда вообще не стоит формулировать определение третьей нормальной формы в терминах транзитивности?

Comment: @AkariGale это просто развёрнутое пояснение для возможности существования транзитивной зависимости в принципе. Так как если разрешить тривиальность X -> Y, то по определению тривиальной функциональной зависимости мы получим ситуацию, не такую что X -> Y, Y -> Z, X -> Z, а совсем другую. Т.е. X -> Y можно рассматривать как просто X (Y как подмножество детерминанта X, будет им "поглащён") и выражение примет вид: X -> Z, которое в свою очередь транзитивным не является по определению.

Comment: Согласен.  Однако все же выходит, что англоязычное определение транзитивной зависимости это не запрещает? Ибо X и Y как раз разные.

Comment: Получается, что этот аспект не актуален в определении третьей нормальной формы, так как такая ситуация блокируется на уровне второй нормальной формы. Поэтому может положить за итоговое определение X → Y и Y →Z нетривиальны, Y → X неверно? Это сохраняет эквивалентность и придает приемлемый вид транзитивной зависимости

Comment: Запрещает "все X, Y, Z различны, и не выполняется Y → X.", обратная функциональная зависимость от Y -> X не должна выполняться.

Comment: Я не понимаю что здесь противоречит тривиальности X → Y. Ну то есть {A, B, C} → {A, B} → {A}, где все атрибуты неключевые. Все наборы атрибутов различны, первая зависимость тривиальна, но обратная не выполняется.

Comment: @AkariGale в качестве доп. источника для понимания сути нормализации отношений могу рекомендовать Вам ознакомиться с Главой 5 Реляционная модель и нормализация из книги Д.Крёнке "Теория и практика построения баз данных".

Comment: @AkariGale https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) почитайте определение тривиальной зависимости. В Вашем примере {A, B, C} → {A, B} → {A}, каждая последующая зависимость тривиальна, так как является подмножеством своего детерминанта.

Comment: в этом весь смысл. Зависимости тривиальны и не противоречат определению: {A, B, C}, {A, B}, {A} попарно различны, {A, B} → {A, B, C} не выполняется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63998/discussion-between-edem-and-akari-gale).